# RLC circuit, integral of current through a capacitor

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, capacitance

[image: the given diagram]

We are asked to find the V$_c$ as a function of time, when its given that the voltage input is exponential
(with $s$ being the frequency) $$ V(t) = V_{o}e^{st}$$
further, upon calculating the impedance $Z$ we get the current to be
$$ i(t) = \frac{Cs}{LCs^2 + RCs + 1} V(t) $$
Therefore the voltage across capacitance $V_c$ is found as
$$ V_c = \frac{1}{C}\int i(t')dt' = \frac{V(t)}{LCs^2 + RCs + 1}   $$

my question is, why are we taking the integral over $t'$ ? is it because there is a phase difference between the current in the capacitor and the rest of the circuit? If so, why is the final integral a function of $t$ and not $t'$ ?
Also, while we're taking the integral, wouldn't a term like this appear finally after taking the limits?
$$ \frac{1}{s}V_{o}(e^{st} - e^{st_o})$$
so, no matter what $t_{o}$ is, wouldn't there be a constant term with as well, that is, if we're not considering $t$ = $\infty$     ?

Answer (score 1):

A good question to ask when bogged down by notation is: "What is happening *physically*?". In this case, the formula for $V_C$ is actually: $$V_C(t) = \frac{Q(t)}{C},$$ where $Q(t)$ is the net charge on the capacitor at some time $t$.

So what is the net charge on the capacitor? Well, you know that there is a "current" in the circuit as the charge begins to get deposited on its plates. Thus, in every interval of time $\text{d}t$ from the moment when the switch was switched "on" (call this $t=t_0$), a charge of $\text{d}Q(t) = I(t)\text{d}t$ is deposited on the capacitor. (Why? Because $I(t) = \text{d}Q(t)/\text{d}t$!)

Now, what is the total charge that accumulates from $t_0$ to some time $t$? Well, you'd need to add up all the infinitesimal $\text{d}Q(t)$s together -- in other words, you'd need to integrate it -- from $t=t_0$ to $t=t$. But if we wrote something horrendous like $$Q(t) = \int_{t_0}^t I(t)\,\text{d} t,$$ this would be just plain confusing, since the $t$ in the limit and the $t$ inside the integral refer to different quantities! The $t$ in the limit is the instant of time at which you want to know how much charge there is on the capacitor, and the $t$ in $I(t)$ is just  a "dummy" variable that is being integrated over: the final answer shouldn't depend on it. As a result, it is good practice to label the "$t$" that you're integrating over by a different name (in your case, the author seems to use $t'$) so that: $$Q(t) = \int_{0}^t I(t')\,\text{d} t'.$$

Notice how I've set $t_0=0$. I assume this is what was intended, since $V_0 = V(t=0)$ usually denotes the "initial" voltage. Integrating this equation, as you point out, one would get something of the form of:

$$V_C(t) = \frac{V(t) - V_0}{LC s^2 + RC s + 1 },$$ but this is simple enough to deal with. Since the term $V_0$ is a constant, one could just redefine $V(t)$ to simply mean the potential *difference* from $V_0$, rather than the potential difference from "$0$". Since such potentials are only specified up to a constant value, I see no reason for this to be a problem.